# Situation with OpenAI API credits

Tags: openai-api

I took openAI api credits (paid with credit card info and everything), but the programme that I ran to use the OpenAI API, has not terminated yet and I'm afraid I'll run out of credits before the task is completed. If that is the scenario, then what will happen?

The credits were taken for industrial purposes. It'll require some time before I get another approval for increasing the api credits.

Please let me know. It's important and any sort of useful answers/comments will be highly appreciated.

I tried looking into OpenAI help desk and online forums but couldn't find anything suitable for my problem.